# Filtering initial load with entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, devexpress

I want to filter my data when I initially load it from database with the following code:

```
_dbContext.PlannedWorkOrder.Where(order => order.ProjectID == _projectid).Load();
plannedWorkOrderBindingSource.DataSource = _dbContext.PlannedWorkOrder.Local.ToBindingList();
```

However when I want to save the changes i get the following error:

> Cannot access the 'ResourceIds' property of a disposed object 'Appointment'.

Everything works just as expected if I load the data without filtering:

```
_dbContext.PlannedWorkOrder.Load();
plannedWorkOrderBindingSource.DataSource = _dbContext.PlannedWorkOrder.Local.ToBindingList();
```

What could be the problem here?

From debugging I could find out that everything happens after schedulerControl1.EndUpdate() method but it looks like the error is from an internal code.Can not really put my finger on it, but it seem it's related to lazy loading...Any ideas?

This works in tandem with xtrascheduler from devexpress btw.

[image]

Stack trace:

```
   konum: DevExpress.XtraScheduler.Native.Exceptions.ThrowObjectDisposedException(String objectName, String propName)
   konum: DevExpress.XtraScheduler.Appointment.get_ResourceIds()
   konum: DevExpress.XtraScheduler.Native.AppointmentChangeHelper.CanChangeAppointment(AppointmentOperationHelper operationHelper, Appointment sourceAppointment, Appointment editedAppointment, Boolean copy)
   konum: DevExpress.XtraScheduler.Native.AppointmentChangeHelper.ValidateOperation(Boolean copy)
   konum: DevExpress.XtraScheduler.Native.AppointmentChangeHelper.PerformDragDrop(ISelectableIntervalViewInfo layoutViewInfo, DragDropEffects effect, Boolean isDrop)
   konum: DevExpress.XtraScheduler.Native.AppointmentChangeHelper.CommitDrag(DragDropEffects dropEffect, Boolean skipRaiseDropEvent)
   konum: DevExpress.XtraScheduler.Native.AppointmentInternalDragAndDropMouseHandlerState.StartDragCore(SchedulerDragData data, ISchedulerHitInfo startHitInfo)
   konum: DevExpress.XtraScheduler.Native.AppointmentInternalDragMouseHandlerStateBase.Start()
   konum: DevExpress.Utils.MouseHandler.SwitchStateCore(MouseHandlerState newState, Point mousePosition)
   konum: DevExpress.XtraScheduler.Native.SchedulerMouseHandler.SwitchToInternalDragState(Point mousePosition, Appointment appointment, ISchedulerHitInfo layoutHitInfo, ISchedulerHitInfo prevLayoutHitInfo)
   konum: DevExpress.XtraScheduler.Native.AppointmentMouseDownState.OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
   konum: DevExpress.Utils.MouseHandler.HandleMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
   konum: DevExpress.Utils.MouseHandler.OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
   konum: DevExpress.Services.Implementation.MouseHandlerService.OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
   konum: DevExpress.XtraScheduler.SchedulerControl.OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
   konum: System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseMove(Message& m)
   konum: System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   konum: DevExpress.XtraScheduler.SchedulerControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   konum: System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   konum: System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   konum: System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   konum: System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
   konum: System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   konum: System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   konum: System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   konum: System.Windows.Forms.Application.RunDialog(Form form)
   konum: System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog(IWin32Window owner)
   konum: System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog()
   konum: Terminator.Forms.FormMainMenu.tileItemProjects_ItemClick(Object sender, TileItemEventArgs e) D:\TErm_Workspace\Terminator\Terminator\Forms\FormMainMenu.cs içinde: satır 24
   konum: DevExpress.XtraEditors.TileItem.RaiseItemClick()
   konum: DevExpress.XtraEditors.TileItem.OnItemClick()
   konum: DevExpress.XtraEditors.TileControlHandler.ProceedPressInItem(MouseEventArgs e, TileControlHitInfo pressInfo)
   konum: DevExpress.XtraEditors.TileControlHandler.ProceedPressInItem(MouseEventArgs e)
   konum: DevExpress.XtraEditors.TileControlHandler.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
   konum: DevExpress.XtraEditors.TileControl.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
   konum: System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   konum: System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   konum: DevExpress.XtraEditors.TileControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   konum: System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   konum: System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   konum: System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   konum: System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
   konum: System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   konum: System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   konum: System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   konum: System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
   konum: Terminator.Program.Main() D:\TErm_Workspace\Terminator\Terminator\Program.cs içinde: satır 23
   konum: System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   konum: System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   konum: Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   konum: System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   konum: System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   konum: System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   konum: System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   konum: System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Comment: Have your issue related to `FetchAppointments` method implementation of DX XtraScheduler? Probably you need to drop calls targeted to `RaisePropertyChanged` which hosts `BindingList`. Also, you may include entire code inside method where `ObjectDisposedException` was thrown.

Comment: No implementation of FetchAppointments actually. Just loads the data on init method.

Comment: It is difficult to tell how the exception thrown from my thoughts, but the exception often thrown when data is refreshed while user doing drag-drop/resizing. You can use `Form.BeginInvoke` method and `schedulerControl1.Services.SchedulerState.IsDataRefreshAllowed` property to handle data refresh, and probably become more clear if you can provide exception stack trace and further details.

Comment: Well,the thing is; i load the data on init event of the form. I do the business  logic on drop pevent, which works flawlessly btw,then at the end i call schedulerControl1.EndUpdate() method since I do a batch update.The exception occurs but not on this method, in the from where i create this form; updated the question with the stack trace

Comment: The `ShowDialog` method throwing exception seems vague in this case, since it's irrelevant with scheduler's activity. Where the `RefreshData()` method being executed (search entire solution to find it)? The given symptoms leads to the scheduler performing data refresh in incorrect way, by calling `RefreshData()` prematurely after data changes has been made.

Comment: Well the funny thing is, refresh data is not called anywhere in this case :(